# Buffer.from() creates an empty buffer when being passed a single number smaller than 16

Tags: node.js, hex, buffer

The following code

```
let num01 = Buffer.from(Number(1).toString(16), "hex");
console.log(num01);

let num02 = Buffer.from("02", "hex");
console.log(num02);

let num16 = Buffer.from(Number(16).toString(16), "hex");
console.log(num16);
```

gives the following output:

```
<Buffer > // how to fix this into 0x01?
<Buffer 02>
<Buffer 10>
```

If I input a decimal number smaller than 16, line one of the code above fails to create a buffer with any values. If I do `Buffer.from("02", "hex");` with a leading zero, then it works fine. How can I modify line one so that it will accept decimal numbers smaller than 16 a create appropriate buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs for Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings), "Data truncation may occur when decoding strings that do not exclusively consist of an even number of hexadecimal characters."

When you create `num01`, you provide the string "1" which is not properly hex-encoded (doesn't have an even number of characters), so it's truncated to nothing.

To turn the argument into an even number of characters, you can use the [padStart method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to pad it with zeros:

```
let num01 = Buffer.from(Number(1).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"), "hex");
```

Or to handle numbers with any number of digits:

```
let value = Number(1).toString(16);
let num01 = Buffer.from(value.length % 2 ? "0" + value : value, "hex");
```

Comment: I guess I'll need some sort of smart padding function, where I will only pad the number, when it is required.

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution that pads any value to an even number of digits.